# What is relation between angles subtended by end-points of a line segment and normal at a point on a parallel line as the point moves on the line?

Tags: integration, geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I don't have the best figure but this is all I got.
[image: Triangle having equal area]
Length of $CD=l_1$ and of $AB=l_2$
$CD||AB $
Perpendicular distance between them$=d$
Therefore $$CE=DF=d$$
Angle subtended by normal and $A$ at any point on $CD$ is $\phi$ and by normal and $B$ is $\theta$
Therefore,
$$\angle ACE=\phi_1 \ \angle BCE=\theta_1$$$$
\angle ADF=\phi_2 \ \angle BDF=\theta_2$$
Let distance moved on $CD$ in directions $C\rightarrow D=x $ and distance of foot of normal on $ AB $ in direction $A\rightarrow B=y$

Now this is part of a problem I encountered in integration: $$\int_0^{l_1}k\left(\sin \phi+\sin\theta\right)dx$$

This meant I had to **find a relation between $x$ and $y$ or $x$ and $(\phi,\theta).$** My geometry failed me.

Please Help.

Comment: Distances of point on $CD$ is measured from $C$ and equals x while distance of foot of normal measured from $A$ is y.

Comment: Hint: can you find the antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(x+a)^2+b^2}}$? For the geometry all you need is the right triangle [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine) of sine and a bit of Pythagoras' theorem. I don't understand why you have this $y$ variable, however you need one more parameter: $AE$ (and then $y=AE+x$).

Comment: And $AE = d\tan\phi_1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Maybe it wasn't clear. But I took $AE=y$ as point moves on $CD$, foot if normal $E$ moves on $AB$ . At $D$ , $E$ becomes $F$

Comment: @Aurelius Ok, it wasn't very clear. However, I still don't see why you would need $y$: once you know $x$ (length on$CD$), you get the length on $AB$ by adding a constant (the $AE$ shown, which is also $d\tan\phi_1$ as noticed by peterwhy). There is just *one* variable, it's $x$. Then if the moving point on $CD$ is $M$ and the foot of the normal is $P$, draw the triangles $MPA$ and $MPB$ and use what you know to find the sines.